how to add a arrow shape in flutter screen
I have a list view with 9 items , and each item has a same dark blue picture in their left
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 9,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/logos/navy-circle.png",
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          'Paragraph ${index + 1}: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor.',
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),

it looks like this :

but i want to add an Arrow icon throw the images , something like this :

any idea? thanks

You can try this:
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 9 + 2, // top and buttom of arrow
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if (index == 0) {
            // end of arrow
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    child: Container(// replace this with your svg arrow tail
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          if (index == 11 - 1) {
            // head of arrow
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    child: Container( // replace this with your svg arrow head
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 8.0,
            ),
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 4,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Paragraph ${index + 1}: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor.',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 13,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      )


NOTE: I don't have svgs of the arrow's head and tail so I used simple white container, you can replace those with your image.

A suggestion for a dynamic screen is to use the Stepper Widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html
/// Flutter code sample for [Stepper].

void main() => runApp(const StepperExampleApp());

class StepperExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const StepperExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Stepper Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: StepperExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StepperExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const StepperExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<StepperExample> createState() => _StepperExampleState();
}

class _StepperExampleState extends State<StepperExample> {
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stepper(
      currentStep: _index,
      onStepCancel: () {
        if (_index > 0) {
          setState(() {
            _index -= 1;
          });
        }
      },
      onStepContinue: () {
        if (_index <= 0) {
          setState(() {
            _index += 1;
          });
        }
      },
      onStepTapped: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _index = index;
        });
      },
      steps: <Step>[
        Step(
          title: const Text('Step 1 title'),
          content: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: const Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'),
          ),
        ),
        const Step(
          title: Text('Step 2 title'),
          content: Text('Content for Step 2'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

steper_example
